# Alternative to nested select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have the following tables structure:

[image]

Currently filtering users is implemented by pretty complex nested SQL query (moreover it is automatically generated by Linq). I looks approximately like:

```
SELECT FROM (SELECT FROM (SELECT FROM ( infinity here...))))
```

Is there a good way to simplify filtering process?

Please, take into account that there are different characteristic types. Here are sub-queries conditions samples:

```
... WHERE cv.Text like '%aaa%' AND c.Id = 5
... WHERE cv.ImageId IS NOT NULL AND c.Id = 10
... WHERE cv.Number > 5 AND c.Id = 33
```

etc...

Will appreciate any help and ideas(change DB structure, change technology, etc...), thanks!

Comment: If it is generated by LINQ then why do you care if it appears complex?  The DB should be 3NF which it appears to be.  You might be missing FK on ImageId and AllowedValueId.

Comment: There are FKs, I just havn't add them to the DB diagram to simplify the view. Actually I don't 100% trust LINQ and I think, that the auto-generated SQL script (that is being 'exec' later) is far from top performance. Maybe some DB-view or stored procedure will provide better results.

Comment: Where is your `LINQ` query?

Comment: It's hard to say by your question how we can improve it. I think you should specify how do you want to filter users, what do you want to get at the end.

Comment: In the end I'll be satisfied with user ids. Now the linq query is generated by number of types, finally it looks like: users.Where(/*condition*/).Where(/*condition*/).Where(/*condition*/).Where(/*condition*/) etc...

Comment: I just look in the SQL Profiler, when I filter users at least by 10 characteristics and I really afraid of the SQL query size. If you need I can provide you with link to the production version of the filter(no login is required to play with it).

Comment: SQL to LINQ is designed to be simple.  It is not the top performer.  Do you have performance issues?   If you only have a few users and moderate database size then it does better than you might think.

Comment: At the moment I'm just doing general optimization of the search functionality. I'm trying to reduce number of requests to the DB and grab only necessary data. I've already done significant part of the work and this query is now the heaviest link in the chain. I'm just wondering if there is possibility to make some optimizations on the early development stage to avoid problems in future.

Answer (score 1):

As you describing it, you query should be something like this

```
select u.id
from Users as u
where
    exists (
        select *
        from CharacteristicValues as cv
        where cv.Text like '%aaa%' and cv.CharacteristicId = 5 and u.Id = cv.UserId
    ) and 
    exists (
        select *
        from CharacteristicValues as cv
        where cv.ImageId is not null and cv.CharacteristicId = 10 and u.Id = cv.UserId
    ) and 
    exists (
        select *
        from CharacteristicValues as cv
        where cv.Number > 5 and cv.CharacteristicId = 33 and u.Id = cv.UserId
    )
```

or even

```
    select distinct cv.UserId
    from CharacteristicValues as cv
    where cv.Text like '%aaa%' and cv.CharacteristicId = 5

    union

    select distinct cv.UserId
    from CharacteristicValues as cv
    where cv.ImageId is not null and cv.CharacteristicId = 10

    union

    select distinct cv.UserId
    from CharacteristicValues as cv
    where cv.Number > 5 and cv.CharacteristicId = 33
```

Comment: In this approach there are also many 'SELECT' statements. I was thinking about 'pivot-like' approach. To generate some tmp table/view with columns: UserId, Characteristic1Value, Characteristic2Value, Ch-c3Val, C4V, ... CnV. If I have such table, then I'll be able to run single 'SELECT' with condition like this: WHERE C1V = 5 AND C7V IS NOT NULL AND C37 > 3 AND C88 LIKE '%Bob%'.

I consider using 'pivot' SQL keyword or OLAP approach. But another problem is that potentially there can be 2-5K+ characteristics and 100K+ users.

Comment: I was analyzing TFS DB structure. It has similar structure to mine DB. Here is correlation: WorkItem <-> User; Field <-> Characteristic; FieldValue <-> CharacteristicValue. TFS supports adding new fields and it have its own WIQL(work items query language). I profiled the query and found out that it is run against aggregated view that contains columns with all fields. But unlikely this approach will not work in my case. Ordinary MSSQL table can have only 1024 columns. Of course I can use wide table... but then the solution will be a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

SQL to LINQ is going to be a poor performer
If you want to optimize performance and scalability then go TSQL

1. DataBase design 3nf
2. Indexes
   And don't over index as they slow down inserts and update
3. Query design
4. Local cache

Local cache
Download static or semi static FK tables at start of exe and save them in Dictionaries.
Then in your pull downs use the Dictionary rather than another call to SQL.
Then in the query I send the FK ID so the select makes one less join (it makes a difference).